# Separate databases, schemas, or another option?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres currently for my database and I am looking for the most logical and efficient solution for the case below:

I have a database set up right now which contains all of the productivity data for every single project in my company. Everything is standard, all columns are conformed, everything is automated (the original data comes from many different sources and formats). I have a whole section of dimension lookup tables and numerous fact tables which are being used for reporting.

I have been asked to add some other information which is much more specific to certain projects and I am trying to think of the best way to go about it. These new tables have nothing to do with the main database and there the type of data being stored will vary wildly per project.

So the overall goal is to have the required, standard, global metrics come from the existing database. Then start to include all of the project-specific data/metrics into an overall data warehouse so there would be a view of total performance for all contractual obligations per individual, date, time period, etc.

- Creating tables in my existing database will become too messy (there are over 1,000 projects which each might have different tables)
- Creating a separate database for each one, or clustering them logically would be fine but would I still be able to do joins between databases? I would not want to replicate the data from my main database. The productivity data would be used for all projects still.
- Is this a case where creating a schema per project (or cluster) would make sense? All projects would relate back to my main database.

The current situation is that each project works in silos. They each have people downloading redundant data and storing it in Excel (probably on their computer which means if they leave or it crashes then the data is lost). There is no single version of truth because things are in Excel or PowerPoint. The goal is to pull everything together and automate some of these tasks out of existence.

**Sample of relations (very simplified, we are dealing with hundreds of potential metrics)**

Existing data has tables like attendance:

```
employee_id | date | start_shift | end_shift | duration
```

Or productivity:

```
employee_id | date | transaction_count | transaction_time
```

And a lot of lookup tables:

```
employee_id | supervisor_name | project_id | project_name | project_category | effective_date | expiration_date | current
```

The new data could come in a variety of formats and will require a lot of ETL, but at the end of the day we should have the date and employee ID at the very least.

```
employee_id | date | survey_count | survey_score
```

So the idea would be to issue reports tying this data together at the lowest granularity (probably daily for most) so end-users could see productivity data and the survey score data in one view.

Comment: which version you plan to use?

Comment: 9.5 currently. Any additional tables/databases I create will be linked back through some foreign keys (project, employee, dates, etc)

Comment: If you plan to split your data in multiples databases/cluster you will need a FDW (like postgres_fdw) to connect a database to another. If you want make it simple, schemas will do the job. Can you provide a sample of relations?

Comment: Sure, I added some in my main comment